# SQL 2017 Linux ag resource not failing over with pacemaker

Tags: sql-server, linux, sql-server-2017, pacemaker, sql-server-linux

We've setup a sql2017 cluster on linux following [MS Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-availability-group-cluster-rhel?view=sql-server-2017).  Replication in the AG works fine but we are unable to failover.  If I watch the logs during failover pacemaker is attempting to move the AG but it fails and continues running on the primary.

On the master it reports the resource not running.

```
Oct 01 15:06:56 [4346] syncdb01a-stag       lrmd:   notice: operation_finished: ttsyncagresource_monitor_11000:6280:stderr [ resource ttsyncagresource is NOT running ]
```

On the secondary I see this unknown error:

```
Oct 01 15:06:57 [24662] syncdb01b-stag  pengine:  warning: unpack_rsc_op_failure:   Processing failed start of ttsyncagresource:1 on syncdb01b-stag: unknown error | rc=1
```

If I run `pcs status` I get the following.  The most recent error it shows is what happens if I shutdown the primary node.  The other two errors were due to sql permissions which are resolved.

```
[root@syncdb01a-stag oper]# pcs status
Cluster name: syncdb-stag
Stack: corosync
Current DC: syncdb01b-stag (version 1.1.20-5.el7_7.1-3c4c782f70) - partition with quorum
Last updated: Tue Oct  1 20:36:32 2019
Last change: Tue Oct  1 15:53:57 2019 by root via crm_resource on syncdb01a-stag

3 nodes configured
3 resources configured

Online: [ syncdb01a-stag syncdb01b-stag syncwit01-stag ]

Full list of resources:

 Master/Slave Set: ttsyncagresource-master [ttsyncagresource]
     Masters: [ syncdb01a-stag ]
     Stopped: [ syncdb01b-stag syncwit01-stag ]

Failed Resource Actions:
* ttsyncagresource_monitor_11000 on syncdb01a-stag 'not running' (7): call=17, status=complete, exitreason='',
    last-rc-change='Tue Oct  1 15:03:47 2019', queued=0ms, exec=0ms
* ttsyncagresource_start_0 on syncdb01b-stag 'unknown error' (1): call=17, status=complete, exitreason='2019/10/01 14:43:30 Did not find AG row in sys.availability_groups',
    last-rc-change='Tue Oct  1 14:43:25 2019', queued=0ms, exec=5255ms
* ttsyncagresource_start_0 on syncwit01-stag 'unknown error' (1): call=17, status=complete, exitreason='2019/10/01 14:43:30 Did not find AG row in sys.availability_groups',
    last-rc-change='Tue Oct  1 14:43:25 2019', queued=1ms, exec=5228ms

Daemon Status:
  corosync: active/enabled
  pacemaker: active/enabled
  pcsd: active/enabled
```

I've also removed any constraints (we are not using a virtual ip due to being multi-subnet)

```
[root@syncdb01a-stag oper]# pcs constraint
Location Constraints:
Ordering Constraints:
Colocation Constraints:
Ticket Constraints:
```

This is the output of `pcs config`:

```
[root@syncdb01a-stag oper]# pcs config
Cluster Name: syncdb-stag
Corosync Nodes:
 syncdb01a-stag syncdb01b-stag syncwit01-stag
Pacemaker Nodes:
 syncdb01a-stag syncdb01b-stag syncwit01-stag

Resources:
 Master: ttsyncagresource-master
  Meta Attrs: notify=true
  Resource: ttsyncagresource (class=ocf provider=mssql type=ag)
   Attributes: ag_name=ttsyncag
   Meta Attrs: failure=timeout=60s notify=true
   Operations: demote interval=0s timeout=10 (ttsyncagresource-demote-interval-0s)
               monitor interval=10 timeout=60 (ttsyncagresource-monitor-interval-10)
               monitor interval=11 role=Master timeout=60 (ttsyncagresource-monitor-interval-11)
               monitor interval=12 role=Slave timeout=60 (ttsyncagresource-monitor-interval-12)
               notify interval=0s timeout=60 (ttsyncagresource-notify-interval-0s)
               promote interval=0s timeout=60 (ttsyncagresource-promote-interval-0s)
               start interval=0s timeout=60 (ttsyncagresource-start-interval-0s)
               stop interval=0s timeout=10 (ttsyncagresource-stop-interval-0s)

Stonith Devices:
Fencing Levels:

Location Constraints:
Ordering Constraints:
Colocation Constraints:
Ticket Constraints:

Alerts:
 No alerts defined

Resources Defaults:
 No defaults set
Operations Defaults:
 No defaults set

Cluster Properties:
 cluster-infrastructure: corosync
 cluster-name: syncdb-stag
 cluster-recheck-interval: 2min
 dc-version: 1.1.20-5.el7_7.1-3c4c782f70
 have-watchdog: false
 start-failure-is-fatal: true
 stonith-enabled: false

Quorum:
  Options:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rebuilt the cluster from scratch and it worked fine, not exactly sure where I went wrong but this time I did a full system update this time before starting.